# Smalltalk and tf-idf algorithm

Tags: nlp, smalltalk, ranking, tf-idf

Can anyone show a simple implementation or usage example of a tf-idf algorithm in Smalltalk for natural language processing?
I've found an implementation in a package called [NaturalSmalltalk](http://www.squeaksource.com/NaturalSmalltalk.html), but it seems too complicated for my needs. A simple implementation in Python is like [this one](http://code.google.com/p/tfidf/).

I've noticed there is another tf-idf in [Hapax](http://scg.unibe.ch/staff/adriankuhn/hapax), but it seems related to analysis of software systems vocabularies, and I didn't found examples of how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the author of the original Hapax package for Visualworks. Hapax is a general purpose information retrieval package, it should be able to work with *any* kind of text files. I just happens so that I used to use it to analyze source code files.

The class that you are looking for is `TermDocumentMatrix`, there should be two methods `globalWeighting:` and `localWeighting:` to which you pass instances of `InverseDocumentFrequency` and either `LogTermFrequency` or `TermFrequency` depending on your needs. Typically when referring to tfidf people mean it to include logarithmic term frequencies.

There should best tests demonstrating the TDM class using a small example corpus. If the tests have not been ported to Squeak, please let me know so I can provide you with an example.

Answer (score 1):

[TextLint](http://scg.unibe.ch/research/textlint) is a system based on [PetitParser](http://scg.unibe.ch/research/helvetia/petitparser) to parse and match patterns in natural language. It doens't provide what you ask for, but it shouldn't be too difficult to extend the model to compute word frequencies.